# adding GameObject at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject, unity3d-2dtools

This may seem like a stupid question but I'm stuck with it. I have GameObjects in a list (`List<GameObject>`) and I want to add them on the scene runtime, prefarbly on predefined places (like placeholders or something). What would be a good way to do it? I've been searching the net but can't really find anything that would solve this. This is my code so far:

```
public static List<GameObject> imglist = new List<GameObject>();
private Vector3 newposition;
public static GameObject firstGO;
public GameObject frame1;//added line

void Start (){
newposition = transform.position;
firstGO = GameObject.Find ("pic1");
frame1 = GameObject.Find ("Placeholder1");//added line

//this happens when a button is pressed
imglist.Add(firstGO);
foreach(GameObject gos in imglist ){
            if(gos != null){
                print("List: " + gos.name);
                try{
                    //Vector3 temp = new Vector3 (0f, 0f, -5f);
                    Vector3 temp = new Vector3( frame1.transform.position.x, frame1.transform.position.y, -1f);//added line
                    newposition = temp;
                    gos.transform.position += newposition;
                    print ("position: " + gos.transform.position);
                }catch(System.NullReferenceException e){}
            }
        }
}
```

How can I place the pics (5) on the predefined spots?

```
//----------------
```

EDIT: Now I can place 1 image to a placeholder (transparent png). For some reason z-value goes all over the place so it needs to be forced to -1f but that's OK. I add the images to the list from other scenes and there can be 1-5 of them. Do I need to put the placeholders in another list or array? I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: I know it's for Unity3D, but maybe this can help you with your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899481/how-to-load-scripts-materials-on-gameobject-in-runtime-in-unity3d/24901026#24901026

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but if I'm correct and you have a list of objects, and you know where you want to move them at runtime, just make two lists, 
one containing the objects and 
one containing transforms of empty game-objects in the scene placed at those predefined positions, and match them at runtime.

Populate both lists from the inspector.

```
public List<GameObject> imglist = new List<GameObject>();
public List<Transform> imgPositions = new List<Transform>();


void Start()
{
    for(var i = 0 i < imglist.Count; ++i)
    {
        imglist[i].transform.position = imgPositions[i].position
    }
}
```

Comment: I came to an almost identical solution myself, I made a Vector3 list (public static List<Vector3> coordinates = new List<Vector3>(); ) of the placeholders and changed the foreach into a for so I can read both lists with the same iterator.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already created 5 new objects you can just do like they do here:
http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/invoke under the InvokeScript

```
foreach(GameObject gos in imglist)
{
    Instantiate(gos, new Vector3(0, 2, 0), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general best way is to create prefabs for your objects, passing them as a parameter and instantiate when needed (Start in your case). That's the common case, but maybe yours is slightly different.

This is an example of passing a prefabs array and to instantiate one object for each one in the array:

```
public GameObject prefabs[];
List<GameObject> objects = new List<GameObject>();

void Start() {
    for(GameObject prefab in prefabs) {
        GameObject go = Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject; // Replace Vector3.zero by actual position

        objects.Add(go); // Store objects to access them later: total enemies count, restart game, etc.
    }
}
```

In case you need several instances for the same prefab (multiple enemies or items, for instance) just adapt code above.

Comment: Using prefabs this way is quite an alien thing to me yet. Thanks for the code, I will test and practice with it :)

Comment: That's pretty basic. You should try the tutorials. It will make your life easier. Good luck!